# Windows Server 2008, "The requested operation requires elevation"

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, uac

Sorry for the newbe question, but I'm a developer who hasn't touch a Windows Server in years.  A recent project has required me to setup and configure a development VM running Windows Server 2008, IIS 7, and SQL Server 2008 Express.  I need to run commands in the command window and get the following message:

"The requested operation requires elevation"

Reminds me of SUDO in Ubuntu, what's the command to elevate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a stab in the dark, but can you right click on the command icon, and select "Run as" and select an account with administrator privileges?

Comment: I'm trying to run a command

Comment: oh, nevermind, I get it

Comment: I right clicked and found "Run as Administrator", and that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you type cmd in the "run" box you can press Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: This works if you type a command in the *"Search programs and files"* box on the Start Menu, but it most definitely does NOT work at the "run" dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, just run the command prompt itself as Administrator, and you won't need to worry about needing elevation.  You will, however, need to worry about having it.