# Having problems with the command ipconfig /flushdns

Tags: domain-name-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Server 2008, “The requested operation requires elevation”](https://serverfault.com/questions/42591/windows-server-2008-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation)

I'm trying to flush the DNS cache using `ipconfig /flushdns` at the command line but I get a message saying `The requested operation requires elevation`. Could someone help me in figuring out the reason behind this please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flushing the DNS cache requires UAC elevation, as do some of the other functions of `ipconfig`.

To run them, you'll need an elevated command prompt.  Right-click cmd.exe and select "Run as Administrator".

[image: runas]